# Render farm and blender

Tags: rendering, command-line

I am tried to render a scene using a render farm service.  When I send the file the system tries to render by using the command line and Blender (2.76b).  The farm uses nodes with no GPU/OpenGL etc...

Blender reports: "failed to read blend file…incomplete" although the same file reads in blender when opened with the Blender GUI app.

Has anyone else had this issue?  I am using 2.77a to create the files.  Reopening and saving in 2.76b and re-running on farm has been tried already.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been resolved by unpacking textures and including them as separate files. Weird.